# auto assign ip address to httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, httpd.conf

I am building a cluster of servers in which new virtual machines will spin up as resources are needed. Is it possible in the apache config file to use a variable that will detect the servers ip address and assign it to a virtualhost instead of me having to specify it manually? Each virtual server will be given a unique ip address and will be built off of a template, but I need a way to change the httpd ip address without having to get in and do it by hand. For example, we have:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.35:8080

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.35:8080>
    ServerName whatever.com
    ServerAlias whatever.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Each server only has a single ip address, but multiple virtualhost entries that would nee

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use the ip-address in the configuration at all? Typically people use `<VirtualHost *:8080>` to bind to all interfaces.

Comment: 5 minutes after posting I came across this very thing. Tested it on a production machine and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Chef/Ansible/Puppet/Salt can do this exactly how you want using a configuration template.

Since I've used puppet the most, [their documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_template.html) shows how to do this.